# PIVOT the rows in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I am having out put like this

Select Referral__C,Type__c from Application__c which will return two rows

```
Referral__C          Type__c 
-----------          -------
5009D000002fEHzQAM   Applicant
5009D000002fEHzQAM   CoApplicant
```

Is there a way we can achieve like this in single query through PIVOT like in SQL

```
5009D000002fEHzQAM    Applicant     CoApplicant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SOQL has no notion of a pivot as such. In some cases, you may be able to use `GROUP BY` or parent-child subqueries to achieve a similar or compatible outcome, although it's not going to provide you with the specific format you've laid out here.

You've omitted key details from your question regarding your schema, but it looks to me like `Application__c` has a lookup `Referral__c` to `Case`, and `Case` has the filed `Type__c`. It's not clear how the two `Application__c` records you're viewing here are related to one another other than that they share a common `Referral__c` `Case`.

You can query from the `Case` level using a parent-child query to get all of the associated Applications in a list:

```
SELECT Id, Type__c, (SELECT Id, ... FROM Applications__r) FROM Case
```

(I'm assuming the relationship name is `Applications`; you may of course want more fields in the child subquery).

Then you can look at each Case and do things like compare the values of `Applications__r.size()` for each row, or iterate through the list and build up a `List<String>` or `Set<String>` of the relevant `Type__c` values.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just gave Raw data for just want to know whether we can acheive PIVOT but since from your explanations these is 'No' i achecived the same through Map. Thanks again